# Creating new ArrayLists Instances in a Constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, constructor

The Global idea : I have a program that's reads a text file (where an assembly program is written) and interprets it . Now i'am trying to develop it using java multithreading ,so that it will be possible that the program reads and interprets diffrent text files at the same time .

The problem : i did a constructor to the class named "Hall_int" where i tried to initialize everything needed because every new Thread must have it's own new variables and ArrayList but unfortunately now the ArrayList gives me a NullpointerExepction when i try to add something to it .
Here is The code :

```
public class Hall_int extends Thread {
    public static ArrayList<String> ProgrammSpeicher;
    public static Float[]reg;
    public static Float accu;
    public static Integer pc;
    public static String line;

    Hall_int() {
        ProgrammSpeicher  = new ArrayList();
        reg = new Float[20] ;
        accu = 0.0f ;
        pc = 0 ;
        line = "";
    }
    ...

    public static void readFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ProgrammSpeicher.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    }
}
```

`ProrammSpeicher` means Programmemory (where the whole programm will be stored) and reg is for registers.

Comment: When you call a static method of a class, the class constructor is not called. Since the static field is only initialized in the constructor (which shows a serious design error), it's not initialized when you call the static method. You need to learn about static variables (and also naming conventions). Using threads, which is extremely hard to do correctly, is way too early for you.

Comment: thank you @JBNizet i will consider these points :)

Comment: remove everything, that is static. Every thread needs their own variables. You need to start a thread with new Hall_int().start() so your static tries do not work.

Answer (score 0):

your Arraylist is static.
everytime you call ProgrammSpeicher, Hall_int.ProgrammSpeicher is returned which is not even initialised i.e a null value is returned.
Also if you want every thread to have its own list with different values,better not to make list static.
Changes made by one thread in list will be seen by the other thread.

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(test.name);
        System.out.println(test.arr);

        test obj = new test();
        System.out.println(test.name);
        System.out.println(test.arr);

        System.out.println(obj.name);
        System.out.println(obj.arr);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class test {

    public static String name;
    public static ArrayList<Integer> arr;

    public test() {
        this.name="Satyam";
        this.arr= new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

output on running test1.java

```
null
null
Satyam
[]
Satyam
[]
```